# Forum Post To Url

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have this project where I have to post data to the url given following specific parameters. I am getting errors and my code is just messy in general. One thing that got me stumped is how I can convert specific values in the JSON object to int. For example the parameter "tickets" requests a integer. Any help would be great.

```
<form class="form" id="form" name="form"  action="https://api.leadprosper.io/ingest" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            <div id="wizard">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
                        <input type="hidden" type="number" id="lp_campaign_id" name="lp_campaign_id" value="5848" required>
                        <input type="hidden" type="number" id="lp_supplier_id" name="lp_supplier_id" value="5848" required>
                        <input type="hidden" id="lp_campaign_id" name="lp_key" value="131bvmpb2" required>
                        <input type="text" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" required>
                        <div class="error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="LastName">Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="LastName" name="LastName" required>
                        <div class="error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="Email">Email</label>
                        <input pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" type="email" id="Email" name="Email"  required>
                        <div class="error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="Phone">phone</label>
                        <input type="phone"  type="text" pattern="^[789]\d{9,9}$" min="1" max="10" id="Phone" Name="Phone" required>
                        <div class="error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="VehicleYear">Vehicle Year</label>
                        <input pattern="[0-9]{1,15}" type="number" id="VehicleYear" name="VehicleYear" required>
                        <div class="error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="PurchaseDateMonth">Purchase Date Month</label>
                        <input pattern="[a-zA-z]{1,15}" type="text" id="PurchaseDateMonth" name="PurchaseDateMonth" required placeholder="September">
                        <div class="error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="PurchaseDateYear">Purchaes Date Year</label>
                        <input pattern="[0-9]{1,15}" type="number" id="PurchaseDateYear" name="PurchaseDateYear" placeholder="2022" required>
                        <div class="error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="FinancedLeased">Finance Leased</label>
                        <select type="text" id="FinancedLeased" name="FinancedLeased" placeholder="">
                            <option value="finance">finance</option>
                            <option value="leased">leased</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class="error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="Goal">Goal</label>
                        <input pattern="[a-zA-Z]{1,15}" type="text" id="Goal" name="Goal" placeholder="">
                        <div class="error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="DailyDistance">Daily Distance</label>
                        <input pattern="[0-9]{1,15}" type="text" id="DailyDistance" name="DailyDistance" placeholder="">
                        <div class="error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="YearlyDistance">Yearly Distance</label>
                        <input pattern="[0-9]{1,15}" type="text" id="YearlyDistance" name="YearlyDistance" placeholder="">
                        <div class="error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="CompCoverage">Company Coverage</label>
                        <select type="text" id="CompCoverage" name="CompCoverage" placeholder="">
                            <option value="yes">yes</option>
                            <option value="no">no</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class="error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="CollisionCoverage">Collision Converage</label>
                        <select type="text" id="CollisionCoverage" name="CollisionCoverage" placeholder="">
                            <option value="yes">yes</option>
                            <option value="no">no</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class="error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="MaritalStatus">Marital Status</label>
                        <select type="text" id="MaritalStatus" name="MaritalStatus" placeholder="">
                            <option value="single">single</option>
                            <option value="married/common law">married/common law</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class="error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label id="dob"for="DOB">Date of Birth</label>
                        <input pattern="?:19|20)[0-9]{2}-(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])|(?:(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:30))|(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])-31" type="datetime" id="DOB" name="DOB" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd">
                        <div class="error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="Occupation">Occupation</label>
                        <input patter="[a-zA-Z]{1,15}" type="text" id="Occupation" name="Occupation" placeholder="">
                        <div class="error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">

                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="genGenderder">gender</label>
                        <select type="text" id="Gender"  name="genGenderder" placeholder="">
                            <option value="male">male</option>
                            <option value="female">female</option>
                            <option value='other'>other</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class="error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="LicenseClass">Licence Class</label>
                        <select type="text" id="LicenseClass" name="LicenseClass" placeholder="">
                            <option value="class 5">class 5</option>
                            <option value="class 5-1">class 5-1</option>
                            <option value="class 5-2">class 5-2</option>
                            <option value="other">other</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class="error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">

                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="DriverAge">Driver Age</label>
                        <input pattern="[0-9]{1,15}" type="text" id="DriverAge" name="DriverAge" placeholder="">
                        <div class="error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="InsuranceCancellation">Insurance Cancellation</label>
                        <select type="text" id="InsuranceCancellation" name="InsuranceCancellation" placeholder="">
                            <option value="no">no</option>
                            <option value="yes">yes</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class="error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">

                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="Suspensions">Suspensions</label>
                        <select type="text" id="Suspensions" name="Suspensions"  placeholder="">
                            <option value="no">no</option>
                            <option value="yes-once">yes once</option>
                            <option value="yes-more">yes more than once
                        </select>
                        <div class="error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="Claims">claim</label>
                        <select type="text" id="Claims" name="Claims" placeholder="">
                            <option value="no">no</option>
                            <option value="yes">yes</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class="error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">

                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="Tickets">Tickets</label>
                        <input pattern="[0-9]{1,10}" type="text" id="Tickets" name="Tickets" placeholder="">
                        <div class="error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="StartDate">Start Date</label>
                        <input pattern="?:19|20)[0-9]{2}-(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])|(?:(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:30))|(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])-31" type="datetime" id="StartDate" name="StartDate" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd">
                        <div class="error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="licenceSince">Licence Since</label>
                        <input pattern="?:19|20)[0-9]{2}-(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])|(?:(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:30))|(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])-31" type="text" id="licenceSince"  name="licenceSince"  placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd">
                        <div class="error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="City">City</label>
                        <input type="text" id="City" name="City" required>
                        <div class="error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label for="state">State</label>
                            <input pattern="[a-zA-z]{2}" type="text" id="State" name="State" required>
                            <div class="error"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="Postal">Postal</label>
                        <input type="text" pattern="[A-za-z0-9]{5}"  id="Postal" name="Postal" required>
                        <div class="error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="sumbit">
                    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
const Form = document.querySelectorAll('form');

Form.addEventListener('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(this);
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams();
   

    for(const pair of formData){
        searchParams.append(pair[0],pair[1]);
        console.log(pair[0],pair[1]);
    }
    console.log(formData);
    const response =  fetch('https://api.leadprosper.io/ingest', {

        method: 'POST',
        body: searchParams,
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;'
        }
    }).then(function (reponse){
       return reponse.json();

    }).then(function(text){
        console.log(text);
    }).catch(function (error){
        console.error(error);
    })
    
})
</script>
```

Payload with the paramaters I need to follow.

```
{
    "lp_campaign_id": "5848",
    "lp_supplier_id": "5848",
    "lp_key": "131bvmpb2",
    "FirstName": "Amelia",
    "LastName": "Nakia",
    "Email": "jbaumbach@example.com",
    "Phone": "3866311306",
    "VehicleYear": 4,
    "PurchaseDateMonth": "Groves",
    "PurchaseDateYear": 1,
    "FinancedLeased": "gray",
    "Goal": "Thursday",
    "DailyDistance": 7,
    "YearlyDistance": 5,
    "CompCoverage": "no",
    "CollisionCoverage": "yes",
    "MaritalStatus": "fuchsia",
    "DOB": "2022-02-03",
    "Occupation": "South",
    "Gender": "male",
    "LicenseClass": "lime",
    "DriverAge": 6,
    "LicensedSince": 2,
    "LicenseLength": "Springs",
    "InsuranceCancellation": "no",
    "Suspensions": "no",
    "Claims": "West",
    "Tickets": 7,
    "StartDate": "2022-02-07",
    "City": "Lake Bailee",
    "State": "AL",
    "Postal": "68820"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want to get only numbers from input, convert your html code to this:

```
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="Tickets">Tickets</label>
                        <input pattern="[0-9]{1,10}" type="text" id="Tickets" name="Tickets" placeholder="">
                        <div class="error"></div>
                    </div>
```

then when you want to get value as an integer type, you should put it in parseInt();
Like this:

```
var data = parseInt(document.getElementById('tickets')) // data is an integer
```

if you want to change value from a JSON object you can simply change the value by reading it like this:

```
data = {
  tickets : 5
}

// to change the number in tickets 

data.tickets = 12
```